# When using Cognito, and creating a policy for AWS IOT, What is the value of the iot:ClientId policy variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to create a dynamic policy for AWS IOT.

I am making a connection to IOT successfully with an open iot policy using
MQTT Over the WebSocket Protocol
as seen here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

Here is what a policy variable is:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/policy-variables.html

What is the value of **iot:ClientId** in the IOT policy, when a connection is made? 
Remember I am connected to the client correctly with cognito session token, etc.
Or, Is there a way I can test these policies in realtime to see what the value of **iot:ClientId** is?

Here is more or less how I am creating a client.

```
let client = new MqttClient(() => {
    const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
        'GET',
        AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST.toLowerCase(),
        '/mqtt',
        'iotdevicegateway',
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'),
        {
            'key': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret': AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            'protocol': 'wss',
            'expires': 15
        }
    );

    return websocket(url, [ 'mqttv3.1' ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of iot:ClientId is the client Id you specify when creating the mqtt connection.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/basic-policy-variables.html

Comment: Thank you for this documentation. I am not sure how I missed this. I just need to set the client Id when establishing the MQTT client.